# Bandwidth utilization tools?

Tags: networking

What commercial or open-source tools are available to measure bandwidth utilization on a network? The tools should provide current and historical snapshots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For monitoring, I would say something like Cacti, Ganglia or Munin. And for alerts, I would use Nagios.

For spot monitoring, ntop is useful for a quick graphical overview. One could always use netstat or tcpdump if you are into the command line stuff.

Comment: do any of these use the .NET stack so we don't need to install other languages?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Windows guy. =)

Comment: Cacti (often) collects data via SNMP, so you could set up Cacti running in a VM monitoring your servers.

Comment: Even MRTG works fine. Have a try.